# Using history.pushState in Angular results in "10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!" error

Tags: html, angularjs, url, pushstate

I'm trying to change the url in my app from "http://www.test.com/foo" to "http://www.test.com/bar+someVariable" *(somevariable is a string that I recieve from an http request inside bar's controller)* using history.pushState() . In my routes I enabled html5mode and everything works fine. I'm also using location.path() to switch between views and controllers as instructed in the docs. Now once the app switches view and controller I added history.pushState(null,null,"/bar"+somevariable) to "/bar"'s controller. Everything works and the url is updated but in the console I receive the "10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!" error. I suspect that activating the history.pushState function is somehow interfering with angular's $location or $route service.

What is the correct way to use history.pushState() within angular without receiving the $digest error?

By the way I'm using angular 1.0.3

Thanks ahead,
Gidon

Comment: I have the same issue when I do some fancy stuff with dynamic includes and dynamically added controllers. Even though it works all fine, as soon as I use, `pushState` everything gets messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Change the path with

```
$location.path('/newValue')
```

See: [http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location)

Comment: Hi oori, I'm already using $location.path(). I'm trying to change the path's url to something new after the reroute. For example using what you provided I would like to route the application to /newValue, but in the url I would like to see /newValue/someVariable, and also have the option to change someVariable according to data received from the server. Do you know how to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not totally sure I get your request,  maybe you could do a simple jsfiddle/plunkr for that example?             I mean,  if the url is set to /x, and then to /x/y, then naturally this is routed by Angular, and $routeProvider kicks in. You could catch those routes there, and stop/manipulate it.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to know for sure without seeing the relevant source, but this is a common issue in older versions of IE (8 and 9 mostly I think).  The solution that worked for me a few weeks ago when I encountered this (and may work for you if you're using IE) was changing my anchor tags in my navigation.

I had:

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

what fixed it:

```
<a href=""></a>
```